Huawei B525s-65a enable VoLTE
I'm trying to enable VoLTE on a Huawei B525s-65a device.
I've tried the following:

visit http://192.168.8.1/html/quicksetup.html as authenticated admin user
run in browser console

var volte_xml = object2xml('request', {volte_enable: 1});
saveAjaxData(
  'api/voice/volte',
  volte_xml,
  function($xml) { console.log(xml2object($xml)) }
);

got this output
error: {code: '100002', message: ''}

100002 seems to mean ERROR_SYSTEM_NO_SUPPORT according to http://192.168.8.1/js/main.js
Am I out of luck? Or, is there another way to enable VoLTE on a MacOS High Sierra (10.13.6)? Also, I don't have a windows box and USB-A-to-USB-A cable.
Or, should I get another device, e.g. TP-Link MR6500V N300 4G WiFi Router?
Thanks.
